# Bindinglist<T> DataGridView with Button control

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindinglist

[image: mockup]

There are TextBoxes in the form and users can enter text, and when they press Add button, a new object of product is instantiated with the provided fields and then it is added to the bindinglist.

Finally this list is binded to the DataGridView and details are shown in the grid. 
(I have done this part).

Now i want a delete button at the end of each row and by clicking that i want to remove the desired row from the list.

but i can't seem to do it i have created a button object in product class and instantiated it with the unique id to remove that object from list. but button is not showing in the row.

and at last by clicking save button the list is saved in the DB.

Comment: Showing the code you have related to this issue is always the best way to get an answer.

Comment: You should add this extra column in your `DataGridView` like `DataGridViewLinkColumn` or `DataGridViewButtonColumn` and then generate an implementation to the event `CellContentClick` where you check if your new column has been clicked and then remove the current databound item in your binding list.